# TweetDeck still displays blocked users in tag search column results, how to fix?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

Using the TweetDeck web interface at https://web.tweetdeck.com/

I have a column that displays the search results for #vmware.  I have @thepingdoctor blocked for mindlessly spamming ads in Twitter proper, and the block is also properly displayed when I look at the user in TweetDeck.

Yet TweetDeck continues to show his tweets in the #vmware results column.

Is this a TweetDeck bug, is there some other way to block a user for good?

Comment: This bug is still in TweetDeck, it's really, really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

**Option 1**

Take a note of their Twitter handle, go to Settings in Tweetdeck.

Within the Settings window, go to the Mute tab.

Under the Mute drop down select **User**. Then in the **Using** box, enter the users Twitter handle then press the **Mute** button.

**Option 2**

In a recent update to Tweetdeck, you can also do it directly from a tweet.

Click their name so it brings up the popup with profile details. Next to the Follow click the drop down button.

Select the **Mute @twitterhandle in TweetDeck** link.

Answer (score 0):

So the way to make sure that those you have blocked in Twitter are not showing up in TweetDeck is to report them for spam from within TweetDeck.  Obviously you only want to do that for people who actually spam.

Comment: I report spam and they still appear :/